# How could I pause till a condition is reached?

Tags: java

When I am coding a game program with Java, I need to obtain the position on the board where the mouse clicks, and then return the position to whatever is behind(legal-move checking, AI, etc.). So how could I let the "behind-part" wait till the user clicks and the panel returns the value?

Comment: look up event listeners

Comment: @MarshallTigerus: would that work with AI? I am more a web framework guy, but from the top of my head I'd say you'd need to utilize notifications and such... synchronized methods all around... that sort of thing.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg not sure I understand your question.  A mouse click can trigger an event listener, which can perform just about any program function.  There's not enough information here to say it would or wouldn't work.  You could code an AI into it, as well as synchronization (disable the event listener until it is finished executing for example)

Comment: @MarshallTigerus Wel, I thought the AI would run in parallel to the user interface... ...I am not sure on how to implement when the AI has reached a conclusion and would like to perform an action.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg depends on what the game is.  If you have an asychronous "thinking" AI, then something else would have to be done (or it could watch for state changes in the board and then start thinking).  If its a simpler game, like tic tac toe or checkers, then an AI could quickly size up the situation and make a good move.   I've built a Dominion AI that needed to know almost nothing about the state of the game that was a pretty strong player

Comment: In either case, the event listener could be used to signal the AI that it is their turn to act, whether they have been thinking the whole time or not